# Object required error in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to run the below macro to enter text in multiple selected sheets. But i get the runtime error "424" Object required

```
Sub CL_Numbering()
Dim shts As Worksheet
i = 1
For Each shts In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
  shts.Range("M3").Value = "EDRC-E-EM-FT-" & worsheetfunction.Text(i, "00") & " R0"
  i = i + 1
Next shts

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: the fifth line. shts.range("M3")....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify to this:

```
Sub CL_Numbering()
Dim shts As Worksheet
dim i as long
i = 1
For Each shts In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
  shts.Range("M3").Value = "EDRC-E-EM-FT-" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "00") & " R0"
  i = i + 1
Next shts


End Sub
```

Comment: Please improve your answer: what you've changed in the code? Why do you think that solves the problem?

Comment: The error was in the worksheetfunction line, I pasted the code I had tested with by mistake. They should also declare i as long (dim i as long).

Comment: Hi i replaced with your code. It worked like a charm. thanks